# Show that $R$ is a Noetherian Ring if and only if $M_2(R)$ is a Noetherian ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity. Show that $R$ is a Noetherian Ring if and only if $M_2(R) = \{\text{2 x 2 matrices with coefficients in } R$} is a Noetherian ring.

I know that $R$ is Noetherian if any of the conditions hold:

- $R$ has the acending chain of ideals condition
- Every ideal in R is finitely generated
- Every nonempty set of partially ordered ideals has a maximal element.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Would you mind editing your question to remind those of us who have been out of the field for a while what $M_2(R)$ is?

Comment: *Hint*: The map $\{\textrm{ideals of $R$}\} \to \{\textrm{ideals of $\textsf{M}_2(R)$}\}, J \mapsto \textsf{M}_2(J)$ is bijective.

Comment: **Hint':** the map @azif00 suggests preserves the order relation on ideals given by inclusion.

Comment: The definition you have given for “Noetherian” is not the widely accepted one.  For a matrix ring, you’d talk about it being *right Noetherian* and define so according to its *right ideals*.  Phrasing as you have, every simple ring is Noetherian, which is not a good outcome.